# change api output from object to array laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have an api that returns an object as wrapper data in result like below :

```
{
data: {
totalSalesPrice: 0,
totalDiscount: 0,
finalPrice: 0
}
}
```

but i want it to be an array like below :

```
{
data: [
totalSalesPrice: 0,
totalDiscount: 0,
finalPrice: 0
]
}
```

or maybe even like below :

```
{
data: [ 
{
totalSalesPrice: 0,
totalDiscount: 0,
finalPrice: 0
}
]
}
```

how can i achive that ?? and here is my method :

```
 public function getPriceDetails($bookingId)
    {
        $booking = AccommodationBooking::where('id', $bookingId)->with('accommodationRoom')->first();
        $roomsOfBook = DB::table('accommodation_booking_accommodation_room')->where('accommodation_booking_id', $bookingId)->get();

        $result = [];
        foreach ($roomsOfBook as $room) {
            $roomPricingHistory = RoomPricingHistory::where('accommodation_room_id', $room->accommodation_room_id)
                ->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $booking->from_date)
                ->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $booking->to_date)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->first();
            $result[] = $roomPricingHistory;
        }

        $totalSalesPrice = collect($result)->sum('sales_price');
        $totalDiscount = 0;
        $finalPrice = $totalSalesPrice;

        $result['totalSalesPrice'] = $totalSalesPrice;
        $result['totalDiscount'] = $totalDiscount;
        $result['finalPrice'] = $finalPrice;
        return new RoomDetailResource($result);
    }
```

Comment: what is in `RoomDetailResource`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to see how you return the data in the RoomDetailResource.
Ideally, to achieve the second result, you could just return a JSON response from 
your RoomDetailResource of the manner:

```
 return response()->json([
        'data' => your_result
    ], status_code);
```

Assuming this is our result to output:

```
$result['totalSalesPrice'] = $totalSalesPrice;
$result['totalDiscount'] = $totalDiscount;
$result['finalPrice'] = $finalPrice;
```

In this case, you get the output:

```
{
data: [ 
  {
    totalSalesPrice: 0,
    totalDiscount: 0,
    finalPrice: 0
  }
]
}
```

Here is a sample from my code:

This is my service and returns a collection.
[image]

This is my controller.
[image]

This is my postman result.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are returning a resource, laravel believes you want to return just one resource.

However, if you want an array of rooms, you can return a resource collection.

```
return RoomDetailResource::collection($result);
```

This will be formatted as

```
data: [ 
{
totalSalesPrice: 0,
totalDiscount: 0,
finalPrice: 0
}
]
}
```